# Changing onCreate causes app to crash on startup; want to have a different starting layout

Tags: java, android, layout, oncreate

My app currently boots directly into a layout, and the onCreate method is used to control that view, for instance responding to button presses and the likes. I wanted however to move to a different initial layout. I initially just moved all of the original control functionality to a new method, and changed the `setContentView(R.layout.main);` to match the new view, this however causes a crash. After some fiddling around I found that no matter what I change within this method I get a crash, even when commenting out minor method calls.

Here is my onCreate method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();
    checkTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

    actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(new ArrayAdapter<String>(actionBar.getThemedContext(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        android.R.id.text1, new String[] {
            getString(R.string.lanc),
            getString(R.string.lanb),
            getString(R.string.lana), 
        }), this);

    final Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");

    latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude);
    longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longtitude);
    orgText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.orgText);
    accpointnameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.accpointnameText);
    floorText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.floorText);

    setlocation();

    installTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
    startActivity(installTTSIntent);

    Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("attempting get from input fields");
            accpointText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.accpointText);
            passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordText);

            IDin = accpointText.getText().toString();
            System.out.println(IDin);
            Passwordin = passwordText.getText().toString();
            System.out.println(Passwordin);

            System.out.println("so far");
            JSONstate = false;

            new JSONDownloader().execute("https://apps.taskpixie.com/arSettings/?id="+IDin+"&password="+Passwordin+"");
        }
    });
    Button cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Why does my app crash no matter what I remove? How can I change my initial layout?

If you need any more data I can provide it, thanks in advance.

---

For example, commenting out `setlocation();` causes the log cat to spit out

> 08-31 14:15:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(12326): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-31 14:15:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(12326): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.bilisattendancerecorder/com.example.bilisattendancerecorder.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   08-31 14:15:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(12326):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2790)
>   08-31 14:15:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(12326):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819)
>   08-31 14:15:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(12326):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
>   08-31 14:15:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(12326):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>   08-31 14:15:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(12326):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
>   08-31 14:15:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(12326):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   08-31 14:15:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(12326):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   08-31 14:15:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(12326):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>   08-31 14:15:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(12326):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   08-31 14:15:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(12326):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>   08-31 14:15:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(12326):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   08-31 14:15:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(12326):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   08-31 14:15:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(12326):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   08-31 14:15:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(12326): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   08-31 14:15:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(12326):    at com.example.bilisattendancerecorder.Main.onResume(Main.java:299)
>   08-31 14:15:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(12326):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1192)
>   08-31 14:15:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(12326):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5211)
>   08-31 14:15:47.120: E/AndroidRuntime(12326):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)

I would like to stress here that changing something so minute should not cause such drastic errors, and that no matter what I take away from this method, I receive errors.

Comment: Can you post the output of `logcat`? It will tell you what caused the exception.

Comment: 08-31 14:03:57.450: E/AndroidRuntime(10243): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.bilisattendancerecorder/com.example.bilisattendancerecorder.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: All of logcat, it will give a line number. Also you'll probably need to post all of your code not just the onCreateMethod(). Edit your answer rather than add it as a comment.

Comment: log cat added, is posting the entirety of my code not a bit much?

Comment: @Margaret what is line 299?

Comment: When resuming or pausing the app location services are paused, by commenting out `setlocation()` I hadn't initialized these location services. This is also what was preventing me from changing the onCreate method. All I needed to do was to not move setLocation() to the new mthod. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.